# Ruby join two arrays by key value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays, the first array contains field name, type and id.

```
arr1 = [
    {
        "n" => "cat",
        "t" => 0,
        "id" => "42WTd5"
    },
    {
        "n" => "dog",
        "t" => 0,
        "id" => "1tM5T0"
    }
]
```

Second array contains field, id and value.

```
arr2 = [
    {
        "42WTd5"=>"meow",
        "1tM5T0"=>"woof"
    }
]
```

How can I join them by id to produce the following result.

```
cat: meow
dog: woof
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _produce_?

Comment: what is that result? Is it an `Array` of `String` values (`["cat: meow","dog: woof"]`) or is it a `Hash` (`{cat: "meow", dog: "woof"}`) or is it just output or a single `String` with a new line break or a rabbit in a hat with a bat? (Please explain)

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: "How can I join them by id to produce the following result." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it.

```
sounds = arr2[0]
results = arr1.map do |animal|
  "#{animal["n"]}: #{sounds[animal["id"]]}"
end
puts results
# => cat: meow
# => dog: woof
```

Seems like the second array should just be a hash instead. There's no point creating an array if there's only one element in it and that number won't change.

pointless one-liner (don't use this)

```
puts arr1.map { |x| "#{x["n"]}: #{arr2[0][x["id"]]}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your result to be a Hash, in which case this would do the job:

```
def match_animals_to_sounds(animal_array, sound_array)
  sounds = sound_array.first
  animal_array.map { |animal| [animal['n'], sounds[animal['id']]] }.to_h
end

>> match_animals_to_sounds(arr1, arr2)
=> {"cat"=>"meow", "dog"=>"woof"}
```

Your `arr2` is unusual in that it is an Array of a single element. I'm just calling `#first` on it to pull out the Hash inside. If you expect some version of this Array to have more than one element in the future, you'll need to rethink the first line of this method.

The second line is standard Ruby Array manipulation. The first part maps each animal to a new Array of two-element Arrays containing each animal's name and sound. At the end, `#to_h` converts this array of two-element arrays to a single Hash, which is much more useful than an array of strings. I don't know what you intended in your question, but this is probably what you want.

If you prefer to work with Symbols, you can change the second line of the method to:

```
animal_array.map { |animal| [animal['n'].to_sym, sounds[animal['id']].to_sym] }.to_h
```

In which case you will get:

```
>> match_animals_to_sounds(arr1, arr2)
=> {:cat=>:meow, :dog=>:woof}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the join result by following code

```
arr1.collect{ |a| {a["n"] => arr2[0][a["id"]]} }
```